# Android ActionBarSherlock Custom View

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have added a custom top bar to my ActionBarSherlock as in

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.my_custom_view);
```

Now this contains an Image Button with the resource id of R.id.back. How do i handle the onclick listener of this item.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also inflate your view if you get a layout inflater and search for the button and then attach a click listener.

So for example something along these lines if your button had id "myButton":

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, null);
Button mybutton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);            
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        /** Your click actions here. */
        }
});
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view);
```