# Add a view below actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbarsherlock in my app. I want to add a view below the actionbar. See the following screenshot:
[image]

I want to add the 4-colored strip to the actionbar. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by creating a `CustomView` for your `ActionBar`.

Then you just got to do this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.my_custom_view);
```

See more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437481/android-actionbarsherlock-custom-view)

Edit: Actually, you can do it using:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_action_bar));
```

Your drawable is something like this:

[image: action bar background]

Comment: Do I have to create whole bar in the xml? I mean the drawer image at the left and the menu action buttons?